# Blazor parameter With Null value

Tags: .net-core, blazor

We have a Blazor Server app core 3.1 , we add a component and call it from navigation like this

```
<a href="/Claimaction" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                        <p>Claims</p>
                    </a>
```

is some time i want to reach this component by other one with parameter like "/Claimaction/PId"
and i want to set this parameter directly by input from component itself
but when call the component from NAV without parameter value the component set
Sorry, there's nothing at this address.
how to solve this issue to allow user set parameter value with three way

1. by Nav like "/Claimaction/100001"
2. by component Input Control
3. Allow open component with Null parameter value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an optional Route parameter.

> [Since .Net5, optional route parameters exist natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters). Just add a `?` at the end of the parameter.

```
@page "/Claimaction/{ClaimsId:int}"
@* if navigation without id, should be possible, this route is needed too  *@
@page "/Claimaction"
  
@* for .NET 5 only on @page directive is needed
    @page "/Claimaction/{ClaimsId:int?}"
*@

@code{

  [Parameter]
  public Int32? ClaimsId { get; set; }

  public override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
  {
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        ClaimsId = ClaimsId ?? -1; // set default value if not set via routing or input
  }

}
```

Because the `ClaimsId` has the name as the router parameter `{ClaimsId:int}`, it is bound when used via Url like /ClaimsAction/10235 (Way 1)

Because `ClaimsId` is a `Parameter` you can set it via binding or any other way. (Way 2). Even if a `@page` directive exists, you could still use it as a "normal" component nested inside other components or your layout.

Because `ClaimsId` is a nullable type, it doesn't require a value at all. If no value is received either via routing or input, the value will be set to `-1`. To achieve this behavior, we override `SetParamterAsync` and set a default value there ( `ClaimsId = ClaimsId ?? -1;`).

I would recommend reading this tutorial too.

Comment: thanks for your replay i will try it soon

Comment: thanks this solve the issue  ,add two @page one with parameter and other without